# PCI-e SSD - Not visible to sysstat's iostat or sar

Tags: rhel, ssd, pci, sysstat

I am attempting to get basic statistics during test runs on a server with a PCI-e attached SSD that is mounted on /dev/rssda1, however sar and other sysstat either do not log, or in the case of iostat return zeros when querying for statistics.

Operating system is RHEL 6.4, any other information available on request.

Appreciate any help on this one!

Comment: FYI. I never found a resolution to this issue.  I also no longer have access to verify any solutions, or investigate any further, so you unless you have any deep insights you may consider this issue closed.